# sonar:sonar doesn't support the "key" attribute

Tags: ant, configuration, sonarqube

I am using Sonar 3.5.1, Java 1.6.0_26 and Apache Ant 1.9.0; and download the plugin sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar under the directory `apache-ant-1.9.0/lib/`.

When I run the ant sonar task, I meet get the error:

> build.xml:115: sonar:sonar doesn't support the "key" attribute

This problem really make me crazy for one week. Can you please tell me what the problem is?

```
<!-- ========= Define Sonar target ========= -->
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="org.codehaus.sonar:${eid}-test" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="${eid}-test" />
<property name="sonar.sources" value="${src.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.language" value="c++" />
<property name="sonar.binaries" value="${classes.dir}" />
<property name="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="${reports.junit.xml.dir}" />   
<property name="sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath" value="${reports.dir}/cppcheck-report.xml" />
<property name="sonar.cxx.gcovr.reportPath" value="${reports.dir}/gcovr-report.xml" />
<property name="sonar.cxx.xunit.reportPath" value="${reports.dir}/gtest-report.xml" />

<!-- The following properties are required to use JaCoCo: -->
<!-- 1. Tells Sonar to run the unit tests -->
<!--
<property name="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="true" />
-->
<!-- 2. Tells Sonar which "tests" targets to run -->

<!-- 3. Tells Sonar to use JaCoCo as the code coverage engine -->
<!--
<property name="sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
-->

<target name="sonar" depends="cppcheck-report">
    <sonar:sonar key="org.codehaus.sonar:${eid}-test" version="1.0" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant" />
</target>

<!-- ========= The main target "all" ========= -->
<!-- Note that depending on the "run-tests" target is not mandatory, as Sonar Ant task will launch it thanks to the "sonar.jacoco.antTargets" property -->
<!-- However, note that compiling is required before running the Sonar Ant task -->
<target name="all" depends="clean,compile,cppcheck-report" />
```

Comment: Have you asked here - http://sonar.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonar-user-f3159782.html ?

Comment: Key attribute is not support by version 2.X of the Sonar ANT task

Answer (score 4):

Here is the link to the Sonar Ant task documentation:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeAntTask-SimpleProject

You'll see that the project key should be defined with help of the `sonar.projectKey` property.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same issue from more than a month and finally got the resolution. I followed a lot of the online help & instructions provided by SonarQube documentation online as well as multiple threads but end up with more frustration.

Then I tried sonar-ant-task 1.5 and followed the build.xml which has the `key` and `version` attributes in the `sonar:sonar` command and it worked. Then I tried this command with sonar-ant-task-2.1 (latest available) and it worked as well.

Well here is my configurations

- JDK: 1.6.0_12 (32 bit)
- Sonar Server: 3.7.2
- Sonar Ant Task Runner: sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar
- Apache Ant: 1.8.4

Following is my ant's build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<project basedir="." default="sonar-runner" name="vApplicationUtilities" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">

<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.5"/>
<property name="source" value="1.5"/>

<!-- Define the SonarQube properties -->
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://my-sonar-server:9000/sonar" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://my-sql-server-host/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="username" />
<property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="password" />
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="my-project-key" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="vApplicationUtilities" />
<property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="4.0.0020" />
<property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
<property name="sonar.profile" value="My Analyzer" />
<property name="sonar.sources" value="src" />
<property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

<path id="vApplicationUtilities.classpath">
    <pathelement location="build/classes"/>
    <path refid="EAR Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
    <path refid="JBoss 5.0 Runtime [JBoss 5.0 Runtime].libraryclasspath"/>
</path>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="build/classes">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build/classes"/>
    <delete dir=".sonar"/>
</target>

<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>

<target depends="cleanall,build-project" name="build">
    <echo message="Creating dist/vApplicationUtilities.jar"/>
    <jar destfile="dist/vApplicationUtilities.jar" basedir="build/classes" manifest="build/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"/>
</target>

<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac includeantruntime="false" debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="build/classes" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="vApplicationUtilities.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target depends="build" name="sonar-runner">
    <!-- run sonar for this project -->
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonar-ant-task-*.jar" file 
            in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
        <classpath path="${lib-dist}/sonar/sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar" />
    </taskdef>
    <!-- Execute Sonar -->
    <sonar:sonar key="${sonar.projectKey}" version="${sonar.projectVersion}" />
</target>

</project>
```

Moreover, you have visited some online help talking about the latest version of sonar ant task (2.x) doesn't need the `key` and `version` attributes in the sonar runner task. It's crap, I have wasted lot of time with that miss leading guidelines. You do need these two attributes to make the sonar task run.

Hope this will brighten your day.
Thanks